# Using vtkDistributedDataFilter on unstructured grids with polyhedron cells

Tags: python, c++, mpi, distributed-computing, vtk

I am using the [vtkDistributedDataFilter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDistributedDataFilter.html) to distribute my data on several processes. Everything is working just fine except when an [vtkUnstructuredGrid](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkUnstructuredGrid.html) has polyhedron cells in it. Then the filter throws a segmentation fault.
Can anyone help me with

1. confirm, that the filter does not work for unstructured grids that have polyhedron cells or
2. tell me how I can make this filter work with polyhedral.

Currently I am

1. instantiating the filter,
2. setting the controller with SetController,
3. setting the input data with SetInputData and
4. finally making the computation with Update.

The following program produces the segmentation fault:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include "vtkMPIController.h"

#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCamera.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkCellData.h>
#include <vtkDataArray.h>
#include <vtkDataSetMapper.h>
#include <vtkDistributedDataFilter.h>
#include <vtkIdList.h>
#include <vtkNamedColors.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkPolyhedron.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  vtkMPIController *contr = vtkMPIController::New();
  contr->Initialize(&argc, &argv, 1);

  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);


  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  printf("%d, %d\n", world_size, world_rank);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> ugrid =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();

  if(world_rank == 0)
  {
    vtkIdType pointIds[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    points->InsertNextPoint(-1.0,-1.0,-1.0);//0
    points->InsertNextPoint( 1.0,-1.0,-1.0);//1
    points->InsertNextPoint( 1.0, 1.0,-1.0);//2
    points->InsertNextPoint(-1.0, 1.0,-1.0);//3
    points->InsertNextPoint(-1.0,-1.0, 1.0);//4
    points->InsertNextPoint( 1.0,-1.0, 1.0);//5
    points->InsertNextPoint( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);//6
    points->InsertNextPoint(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);//7

    points->InsertNextPoint( 2.0,-1.0,-1.0);//8
    points->InsertNextPoint( 2.0, 1.0,-1.0);//9
    points->InsertNextPoint( 2.0,-1.0, 1.0);//10
    points->InsertNextPoint( 2.0, 1.0, 1.0);//11

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> faces =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
    vtkIdType face0[4] = {0, 3, 2, 1};
    vtkIdType face1[4] = {0, 4, 7, 3};
    vtkIdType face2[4] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
    vtkIdType face3[4] = {5, 1, 2, 6};
    vtkIdType face4[4] = {0, 1, 5, 4};
    vtkIdType face5[4] = {2, 3, 7, 6};

    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face0);
    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face1);
    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face2);
    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face3);
    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face4);
    faces->InsertNextCell(4, face5);

    vtkIdType pointIds2[8] = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11};

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> faces2 =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
    vtkIdType face6[4] = {5, 1, 2, 6};
    vtkIdType face7[4] = {1, 2, 9, 8};
    vtkIdType face8[4] = {2, 6, 11, 9};
    vtkIdType face9[4] = {6, 5, 10, 11};
    vtkIdType face10[4] = {5, 1, 8, 10};
    vtkIdType face11[4] = {11, 10, 8, 9};

    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face6);
    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face7);
    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face8);
    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face9);
    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face10);
    faces2->InsertNextCell(4, face11);

    ugrid->SetPoints(points);
    ugrid->InsertNextCell(VTK_POLYHEDRON, 8, pointIds, 6, faces->GetPointer());
    ugrid->InsertNextCell(VTK_POLYHEDRON, 8, pointIds2, 6, faces2->GetPointer());
  }

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistributedDataFilter> distFilter =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistributedDataFilter>::New();

  distFilter->SetInputData(ugrid);
  distFilter->SetController(contr);
  distFilter->Update();

  MPI_Finalize();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled with this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(Polyhedron)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(Polyhedron MACOSX_BUNDLE Polyhedron.cxx )

target_link_libraries(Polyhedron ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```